# How to use IF statement with $id = Auth::id(); to get users id Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I've searched everywhere for this and tried to make it happen all day today, but still can't figure it out.

Basically I am trying to use IF statements in routes to display appropriate info to users with appropriate ID.

But I am getting

```
Function name must be a string
```

For this

```
if ($user = $id(8))
```

I can't figure out how to pass in current users id to  that if statement to check it. Sorry if dumb question, but I'm just starting with Laravel.

```
Route::get('/secret', function()
{
$user = Auth::user();
$id = Auth::id();

if ($user = $id(8))
{
    return 'It worked!';
}

return 'Your id is not 8.';
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use `if($user = $id(8))`, try to use: `if($id == 8)` instead. You want to compare two values, so you need to use `==`, `=` means assigning a value.

Hope it works!
By the way: you don't have to use the `$user` variable as far as I can see. `$id` is enough in your case ;)

Comment: Thank You! It worked. And I was always wondering what for there is '=='. Thanks again.

Comment: @JohnLV You're welcome! Could you mark my answer as the solution for your problem please? Just click the button at the left side of my answer :)

Comment: Sure @Robin, just had to wait 5 mins before it can be done ;)

Answer (score 0):

JohnLV's answer is correct, but you look like you might be better off making a route filter - read here for more information:

http://laravel.com/docs/routing#route-filters

This is for when you want to block access to certain pages/routes based on user privileges (i.e. hide admin area from users).

But if you want to change things in you view based on user id, then it is best to put this code in the controller.

Comment: Thanks for this info, but where from would Route Filters get info, would it come from DB? Thanks for leading me in right direction.

Comment: yes, take your original code and dump it into a route filter, then instead of returning "your id is not 8" you would redirect to another route like a login page

Comment: Thanks, will definitely include this in my project.